# How to set defaultTab in easyTabs all-dominant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm loading by ajax content in a div-container by several navigation links and using this following script to set the defaultTab:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#tab-container").easytabs({updateHash: true, defaultTab: "li:eq(3)"});
});
```

That works fine until **I get used something like '#tab1-9' in the url by clicking on a tab**. Then it doesn't matter how I set the defaultTab.

How can I set this defaultTab despite of the content in the url?

Comment: can you provide any jsfiddle or runnable code snippet?

Comment: I need a possibility to prevent the output of something like that '#tab1-4' behind the url or to modify this when the script load the file by 
'
    $(function() {
  $('#content').load('./srv/inc/content.inc.php?welle=1&markt=2');
    });

    <div id="content"></div>
'
**This load-function does not change the url in the address bar.** That's the 'annoying' point.
coz the extension in the address bar determine the selected tab, not the attribute 'defaultTab'.
In fiddle there is not a address bar to show this problem.
Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: are you using [this](https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) plugin?

Comment: Yes.


Thats why: '$("#tab-container").'**easytabs**'({updateHash: true, defaultTab: "li:eq(3)"});'

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the tab on page reload even if url contains some #tabId. That plugin has a method built in for this.

> EasyTabs currently has one public method, called select, which allows
>   you to select a tab via JavaScript.

Just add this code in your `$(document).ready()` function:
`$('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#default-tab-link');` after this line: `$("#tab-container").easytabs({updateHash: true, defaultTab: "li:eq(3)"});`

Then your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#tab-container").easytabs({updateHash: true, defaultTab: "li:eq(3)"});
  $('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#default-tab-link');
});
```

And in your html code, inside third `li` item(which you want to be default) set the `id` attribute of `<a>` tag to `default-tab-link`

Comment: It doesn't work like I want. -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5C6h/2034/)

if you reload the frame, you get the clicked tab not the defaultTab. If I use a javascript variable would be the same like php-Variable by loading the file by ajax-load(). It doesn't change anything there.

Comment: in jsfiddle if you check the url then you see that it doesn't contain any #tabid and it can't simulate that scenario. I've tested it in local machine and it's working properly. can you please do so, and let me know?

Comment: I tested also in the local machine and there is the same thing. Maybe we think differntly. It has to change to the defaultTab by loading the frame. That would be nice. That means that probably has to change the url by loading the file surely. your script doesn't do that.
**(after clicking on an other tab) It has to change to the value of the variable nTab by loading the frame again**.

Comment: I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminur/T5C6h/2036/), now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found:

```
$("#tab-container").easytabs({updateHash: true, defaultTab: "li:eq("+nTab+")", active: nTab});
$('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#tabs1-'+String.fromCharCode(nTab+97));
```

This works also in [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5C6h/2035/).

Thank you very much for your hint.